# .htaccess rewrite, for all directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I have errors which are passed by the url, for example

```
index.php?error=nojs
```

will then be parsed by PHP to return an error message, for example: Please enable Javascript

I'm using the following line in my .htaccess to make the url easier to manage

```
RewriteRule ^ERROR_(.*)$ index.php/?error=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It makes my URL look like this:
    site.com/ERROR_nojs

The problem is, this only works for the root,

```
index.php?error=nojs        works fine however
test/index.php?error=nojs   does not?
```

So how can I convert the variable for every directory?

Thank you. (My original script handles hundreds of errors and filters out ones that might be useful to output to the user. It would be stupid to redirect them to the index just so they can see a small  with an error message in it)

```
EDIT:
```

as Shai Mishali pointed out removing the '^' before ERROR did the trick.

```
RewriteRule ERROR_(.*)$ index.php/?error=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

But I forgot to tell you I have another variable ?page=

I need get that vairbale and add it to the url in order for this to work..

e.g:

```
index.php?page=home&error=nojs
= site.com/home/ERROR_nojs
```

so

```
 www.site.com/?page=home&error=nojs   = www.site.com/home/ERROR_nojs
```

or

```
 www.site/?page=about&error=unknown  = www.site.com/about/ERROR_unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is your rule is looking for something that starts with ERROR (the ^ sign) .

/ERROR starts with error, which works in your root , but
/tests/ERROR starts with tests , so it won't recognize it.

Try removing the ^ sign and see what happens.

Shai.

Comment: Thank you it was a nice idea but it only results in a redirect error.

Comment: This might work actually, I had other variables I didn't mention in my example. Thank you.

Comment: If you still need help feel free to edit your question and ill try to assist. If this helped you don't forget to accept my answer ;-) Cheers.

Comment: Fire away sir, I tried to make my issue as simple to understand, it just involves converting yet another variable- something I have difficulty with.

Comment: Hey Billy, as Ashok suggested you could try something like 

RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/ERROR_(.*?)$ index.php/?page=$1&error=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)$ ./index.php?page=$1&error=ERROR_$2 [NC]
```

Your URL site.com/home/ERROR_nojs will treated as index.php?page=home&error=nojs  and you can get the values by GET method. For more [info](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)